# PostgreSQL won't start

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I installed Postgresql on Ubuntu 18.10 (on a VPN) and was unable to connect to it. At this point I did:

```
ps -f -u postgres
```

and got the shocking result of.... absolutely nothing. I ran htop to double check this and, sure enough, there is no running postgresql running service. I was initially able to run psql and issue commands, which would make me assume that before it was reset it was running postgresql but post reset it has not surviced. But I have tried starting the service and it tells me it cannot find the service?

The version is 10 and the conf files are in /etc/postgresql/10/main. But those files don't matter I suppose since it is not running.

I do have a /var/run/postgresql directory with the folder "10-main.pg_stat_tmp" in it, which doesn't sound promising.

Can anyone help please? I apologise if this is not in the correct place but I thought DB admin was more relevant than Ubuntu forums and more likely to have someone that knows the answer. Thanks, Kevin.

EDIT: Some info from the log above:

```
2019-01-20 10:11:31.116 UTC [2118] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-01-20 10:11:31.117 UTC [2118] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-01-20 10:11:31.118 UTC [2118] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-01-20 10:11:31.139 UTC [2118] LOG:  invalid IP mask "md5": Name or service not known
2019-01-20 10:11:31.139 UTC [2118] CONTEXT:  line 94 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf"
2019-01-20 10:11:31.139 UTC [2118] LOG:  invalid IP mask "md5": Name or service not known
2019-01-20 10:11:31.139 UTC [2118] CONTEXT:  line 96 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf"
2019-01-20 10:11:31.139 UTC [2118] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
2019-01-20 10:11:31.142 UTC [2118] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

Comment: The *"LOG:  invalid IP mask "md5""* and *"FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf"* are revealing;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution! Putting this here for anyone who has a similar problem. When I altered the ph_hba.conf and added in my IP address at the end I forgot to put it in the form `host all all a.b.c.d/32 md5`. I had put `host all all a.b.c.d md5` leaving out the /32 at the end of the ip address. I had similarly left off the /128 on the IPv6 line.

I hope this is useful to someone who cannot connect to postgresql on UBuntu 18.10 and doesn't realise it is because the thing isn't actually running!

Comment: Thank you for helping me return to sanity. There were no other real indications of what could have been causing postgres to not start. That was frustrating.